# Knockout Binding Select Change with MVC 5

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, knockout.js, knockout-3.2

I'm using Knockout's "foreach" function on my MVC application's model to load a table of dropdown options. When the selected dropdown value changes, I need to track that change in the model.

I tried using the subscribe option on the element in the model, but when it changes, the function I bound to it isn't firing. I'm aware there are several ways of implementing this change, but I'd prefer to stick with this format of defining my functions as shown at the bottom of the view.

Model:

```
    public class ProfileLookAndFeelViewModel : StandardLayoutViewModel
        {
            public ProfileLookAndFeelViewModel()
            {
                Form = new FormGroup();
                PriceUOMDropdownOptions = new PriceUOM();
                UOMInformation = new UOMInformationGroup();
            }

            public FormGroup Form { get; set; }
            public PriceUOM PriceUOMDropdownOptions { get; set; }
            public UOMInformationGroup UOMInformation { get; set; }

            public class FormGroup
            {            
                public bool FormValueChanged { get; set; }            
            }

            public class PriceUOM
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public String Name { get; set; }
                public string Code { get; set; }
            }

            public class PriceUOMOverride
            {
                public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
                public string TemplateCode { get; set; }
                public string UOMDesc { get; set; }
                public List<PriceUOM> PriceUOMDropdownOptions { get; set; }
                public int SelectedPriceUOM { get; set; }
                public int SelectedPriceUOMOriginal { get; set; }
                public bool SelectedPriceUOMChanged { get; set; }
            }  

            public class UOMInformationGroup
            {
                public UOMInformationGroup()
                {
                    UOMs = new List<PriceUOMOverride>();
                }

                public List<PriceUOMOverride> UOMs { get; set; }
                public bool UOMsChanged { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

View:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Template Code</th>
                <th>Default UOM</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- ko foreach: $root.UOMInformation.UOMs -->
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: ItemDescription"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: TemplateCode"></td>
                <td class="center" >
                    <select data-bind="options: PriceUOMDropdownOptions, optionsText: 'Code', optionsValue: 'Id', value: SelectedPriceUOM, css: { important: SelectedPriceUOMChanged() == true }"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
    </table>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var vmProfileLookAndFeel = function () { var self = this; };
        vmProfileLookAndFeel = ko.mapping.childrenIndependently($.parseJSON('@Html.RawJsonForKoMapping(Model)'), ["UOMInformation", "Form", "PriceUOMDropdownOptions"]);
        vmProfileLookAndFeel.UOMInformation.UOMs.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            vmProfileLookAndFeel.ValueChanged();
        });

        vmProfileLookAndFeel.ValueChanged = function () {
            //Do something;
        };

        ko.applyBindings(vmProfileLookAndFeel);
        });
    </script>
```

I tried this suggestion but answer here isn't loading data from a MVC model but a hard coded array

[Subscribe to select item from foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824234/subscribe-to-select-item-from-foreach-loop)

**EDIT:**

I updated the view to reflect adding the array as observable.

Here is the function that I call to map the objects

```
    ko.mapping.childrenIndependently = function (jsObject, childrenArray) {
        var mapping = {
            "ignore": childrenArray
        }
        var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsObject, mapping);

        // handle children
        for (var childrenArrayIndex = 0; childrenArrayIndex < childrenArray.length; childrenArrayIndex++) {
            if (jsObject.hasOwnProperty(childrenArray[childrenArrayIndex])) {
                // if the property is an array, create an objservable array
                // and map each child
                // else map the property
                if ($.isArray(jsObject[childrenArray[childrenArrayIndex]])) {
                    vm[childrenArray[childrenArrayIndex]] = ko.observableArray();

                    for (var childObjectArrayIndex = 0; childObjectArrayIndex < jsObject[childrenArray[childrenArrayIndex]].length; childObjectArrayIndex++) {
                        vm[childrenArray[childrenArrayIndex]].push(ko.mapping.childrenIndependently(jsObject[childrenArray[childrenArrayIndex]][childObjectArrayIndex], childrenArray.slice(childrenArrayIndex)));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    vm[childrenArray[childrenArrayIndex]] = ko.mapping.childrenIndependently(jsObject[childrenArray[childrenArrayIndex]], childrenArray.slice(childrenArrayIndex));
                }
            }
        }

        return vm;
    };
```

Comment: You have no observables. You can't just declare things as get/set, they need to be observables. Otherwise Knockout doesn't know to observe them.

Comment: You're right. That seems to be a step in the right direction, but I'm still not seeing the function fire on selection changing.

Comment: If you want something to happen when the selection changes, you need `SelectedPriceUOM` to be an observable, and you need to put your subscribe onto it.

Comment: How do you subscribe to SelectedPriceUOM when there are a list of them in the UOMInformation.UOMs collection? I'm subscribing to UOMs, and I think each SelectedPriceUOM within is observable.

Comment: This is a tangent, but you really shouldn't (need to) do stuff like subscribing and calling ValueChanged() when using knockout. It's an anti-pattern and will bite you hard if/when you work with large and complex Viewmodels. Set up your observables properly (computeds are your friend) and the change notifications are all dealt with automagically.

Comment: I just want to let the user know the value they're looking at on their table has changed (by them) and I will apply a CSS that makes it look visually different so they know they changed it. There is a save button that will pass the model with the changes back to the controller. What makes this an anti-pattern?

Comment: Have you been through the Knockout tutorial? It is worth your time. http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Comment: Yeah but I haven't seen a scenario like this before. Most of the examples revolve around a formatting different than what I'm building off of. For example, my script is one giant jQuery function with the bindings applied within. Also the data it uses is static. I'll revisit it to make sure I didn't miss anything. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario I end up adding a calculated function hidden immediately after the `<select>` element that would get called each time a row is added. From there I could manipulate the object as it was being generated.

```
    <td class="center" >
        <select data-bind="options: PriceUOMDropdownOptions, optionsText: 'Code', optionsValue: 'Id', value: SelectedPriceUOM, css: { important: SelectedPriceUOMChanged() == true }"></select>
        <span class="hide" data-bind="text: $root.OnTheFlyCalculations($data)()"></span>
    </td>
```

New Function

```
    vmProfileLookAndFeel.OnTheFlyCalculations = function (item) {
        return ko.computed({
            read: function () {                 
                return item.SomethingChanged(true);
            }
        }, vmProfileLookAndFeel)
    };
```